# Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: jpa+springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

model classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RequisitionRequest")
public class Requisition {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String requestedPerson;
    private String contactDetails;
    private String appliedDate;
    private String branch;
    private String department;

    private String status;
     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "RequisitionRequest")
    private List<Nationality> nationality;
//getters and setters
}
```

class Nationality

```
@Entity
@Table(name="nationality")
public class Nationality {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String nationality;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "nationality_id", nullable = false)
    private Requisition requisition;
//getters and setters
}
```

repository classes

```
@Repository
public interface NationalityRepository extends JpaRepository<Nationality,Long>{

}

@Repository
public interface RequisitionRepository extends JpaRepository<Requisition,Long> {

}
```

service class

```
@Service
public class RequisitionServiceImpl implements RequisitionService {
    @Autowired
    RequisitionRepository requisitionRepository;

    @Override
    public void save(Requisition requisition) {
        requisitionRepository.save(requisition);

    }
}
```

controller class

```
@RestController
public class RequisitionController {
    @Autowired
    RequisitionService requisitionService;

    @Autowired
    RequisitionRepository requisitionRepository;
@PostMapping("/requisition/")
    @CacheEvict(value = "requisitions", allEntries=true)
    public ResponseEntity<Requisition> addRequisition(@RequestBody Requisition requisition) {
        System.out.print(requisition);

        Requisition requisitionR = new Requisition();
        Requisition response = new Requisition();




        requisitionR.setBranch(requisition.getBranch());
        requisitionR.setDepartment(requisition.getDepartment());
        requisitionR.setExpectedDateofJoin(requisition.getExpectedDateofJoin());

        //requisitionR.setNationality(requisition.getNationality());


        requisitionRepository.save(requisitionR);


        return new ResponseEntity<Requisition>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

i am learning spring boot,just writing sample program  to learn spring boot+jpa+one-to-many relation.when execute this above code getting error like

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: officekitRecruitment.model.Nationality.RequisitionRequest in officekitRecruitment.model.Requisition.nationality
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:769) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:719) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]

I tried the solutions already mentionned in this site but it doesn't work for me.
Can anybody helps me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer to the name of the Field in mapped entity on your MappedBy parameter.

Like that

```
mappedBy = "requisition"
```